# Communication failure error (Tomcat or MySQL issue?)

Tags: mysql, tomcat, connection, timeout, tomcat6

I have a webservice which from time on time throw this error:

```
Excepcion:com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: 
Communications link failure
Last packet sent to the server was 1 ms ago.
```

After some research made it took me to think about the timeout variables in mysql. At first i edited the vars and they were like this:

```
[mysqld]
interactive_timeout=300
wait_timeout=300
connect_timeout=20
```

But following recommendations returned it to:

```
[mysqld]
interactive_timeout=28800
wait_timeout=28800
connect_timeout=20
```

And the timeout connection of tomcat is

```
<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
 port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
 connectionTimeout="20000" maxConnections="300"
 redirectPort="8443" maxThreads="100"/>
```

- The maxConnections are never reached,
  neither the max connections of Mysql
- Me and my my co-workers tested the service in many random hours of the day and no error showed up, just a few workers on other office have seen this error happen on their requests
- And the time on wich the error is throwed doesn´t match any timeout var,
  Is almost a random time.

Where should I look or which value should i change to avoid this error?
Tomcat?
MySQl?
WebService?